# Why nobody does not make it in the docker? (All-in-one container/"black box")

Tags: linux, docker, cloud, containers, virtualization

I need a lot of various web applications and microservices.

Also, I need to do easy backup/restore and move it between servers/cloud providers.

I started to study Docker for this. And I'm embarrassed when I see advice like this: "create first container for your application, create second container for your database and link these together".

**But why I need to do separate container for database?** If I understand correctly, the main message is the docker the: "allow to run and move applications with all these dependencies in isolated environment". That is, as I understand, it is appropriate to place in the container application and all its dependencies (especially if it's a small application with no require to have external database).

### How I see the best-way for use Docker in my case:

1. Take a baseimage (eg phusion/baseimage)
2. Build my own image based on this (with nginx, database and
   application code).
3. Expose port for interaction with my application.
4. Create data-volume based on this image on the target server (for store application data, database, uploads etc) or restore data-volume from prevous backup.
5. Run this container and have fun.

### Pros:

1. Easy to backup/restore/move application around all. (Move data-volume only and simply start it on the new server/environment).
2. Application is the "black box", with no headache external dependencies.
3. If I need to store data in external databases or use data form this - nothing prevents me for doing it (but usually it is never necessary). And I prefer to use the API of other blackboxes instead direct access to their databases.
4. Much isolation and security than in the case of a single database for all containers.

### Cons:

1. Greater consumption of RAM and disk space.
2. A little bit hard to scale. (If I need several instances of app for response on thousand requests per second - I can move database in separate container and link several app instances on it. But it need in very rare cases)

**Why I not found recommendations for use of this approach? What's wrong with it? What's the pitfalls I have not seen?**

Comment: For small environment, that's no wrong to put all-in-one.

Comment: You can do it if you'd like, that's OK. But you're going to have problems with scalability this way. What if you have to create two or more instances of your app which connect to one database?

Comment: @starikovs yes you're right. But if I need two or more instances of app I can move database in separate container and link app containers with db container, as everyone advice, right? :) But the point is that as long as such a need arises I prefer to keep everything in one place. Thank you for answer!

Comment: @yokotoka sure, you can do it as you'd like :)

Comment: @yokotoka You'll get on much better if you understand that a Docker container is basically a process.  So your question becomes "why I need to do separate process for database?". But the benefits of isolation are also useful - for instance suppose your database requires a different version of Python to your application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand a Docker container is not a virtual machine, just a wrapper around the kernel features chroot, cgroups and namespaces, using layered filesystems, with its own packaging format. A virtual machine usually a heavyweight, stateful artifact with extensive configuration options regarding to the resources available on the host machine and you can setup complex environments within a VM.

A container is a lightweight, throwable runtime environment with a recommendation to make it as stateless as possible. All changes are stored with in the container that is just a running instance of the image and you'll loose all diffs in case of container deletion. Of course you can map volumes for more static data, but this is available for the multi-container architecture too.

If you pack everything into one container you loose the capability to scale the components independently from each other and build a tight coupling.

With this tight coupling you can't implement fail-over, redundancy and scalability features into your app config. The most modern nosql databases are built to scale out easily and also the data redundancy could be a possibility when you run more than one backing database instance.

On the other side defining this single-responsible containers is easy with docker-compose, where you can declare them in a simple yml file.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a bit out of date: Docker has not used LXC for about a year.  More correctly "just a wrapper around the kernel features chroot, cgroups and namespaces, using layered filesystems, with its own packaging format"